# a wrong about shader

Tags: directx, shader

I try to study the directx3D, but I'm having a problem about D3DXCompileShaderFromFile. this is a part of my code.

```
ID3DXBuffer* pShader;

ID3DXBuffer*    error_buffer;

HRESULT  hr =D3DXCompileShaderFromFile(L"Transform.txt", NULL, NULL, "vs_main", "vs_3_1", 
D3DXSHADER_DEBUG, &pShader, &error_buffer, &g_pConstantTable);

/*创建着色器对像*/

g_pd3dDevice->CreateVertexShader( (DWORD*)pShader->GetBufferPointer(), &g_pVertexShader );

pShader->Release();
```

The problem is that the `pShader` can't get value by `D3DXCompileShaderFromFile`, the value of `pShader` is `NULL`, so that it can't perform operations `CreateVertexShader`.
So, Why this error?

Comment: The result of the function "hr" should tell you if it failed, and your error_buffer should contain a specific error if the shader failed to compile. Have you looked at either of those?

Comment: That call will certainly fail. There is no profile ``vs_3_1``.

Comment: Firstly, I assume you are using Direct3D 9 here since you are using the deprecated D3DX9 library. Even for older 2.0 and 3.0 shader profiles, you can use the ``D3DCompile`` API directly instead of going through D3DX9. See [HLSL, FXC, and D3DCompile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx). Unless you only have access to Windows XP era systems, I'd recommend learning Direct3D 11 instead.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn What is no profile? I can't understand. Can you explanation it? thanks.

Comment: @jcoder I konw it and I tried the outset. But unfortunately, here is some garbled, I can't understand that.

Comment: The FXC HLSL compiler only supports the following shader profiles which must match the hardware you intend to run the shader on: ``cs_4_0 cs_4_1 cs_5_0 ds_5_0 fx_2_0 fx_4_0 fx_4_1 fx_5_0 gs_4_0 gs_4_1 gs_5_0 hs_5_0 ps_2_0 ps_2_a ps_2_b ps_2_sw ps_3_0 ps_3_sw ps_4_0 ps_4_0_level_9_1 ps_4_0_level_9_3 ps_4_0_level_9_0 ps_4_1 ps_5_0 tx_1_0 vs_1_1 vs_2_0 vs_2_a vs_2_sw vs_3_0 vs_3_sw vs_4_0 vs_4_0_level_9_1 vs_4_0_level_9_3 vs_4_0_level_9_0 vs_4_1 vs_5_0``. You will note that ``vs_3_1`` is not one of these. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509626.aspx).